# ImportError: No module named _sqlite3 (even after doing eveything)

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, sqlite

i am using python 2.7.11 on virtualenv in lubuntu 12.04.(dont own a good laptop its dell latitude d600)

```
Python 2.7.11 (default, Mar  4 2016, 04:38:41)
```

[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import sqlite3
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/home/maharshi/.localpython/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/**init**.py", line 24, in 
> > >           from dbapi2 import *
> > >         File "/home/maharshi/.localpython/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 28, in 
> > >           from _sqlite3 import *
> > >       ImportError: No module named _sqlite3

i have installed pysqlite using pip and it says successfull.

```
(p2.7) maharshi@maharshi-Latitude-D600:~/code$ which python
/home/maharshi/virtualenvs/p2.7/bin/python
(p2.7) maharshi@maharshi-Latitude-D600:~/code$ which pip
/home/maharshi/virtualenvs/p2.7/bin/pip
(p2.7) maharshi@maharshi-Latitude-D600:~/code$ pip install pysqlite
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pysqlite in /home/maharshi/virtualenvs/p2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

i also installed it manually at both locations i.e

```
~/virtualenvs/p2.7/
~/.localpython/ (from where i created the virtualenv)
```

i also installed "`libsqlite3-dev`(as suggested by one of the posts)" i.e

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing the whole process again installing python in virtualenv...as i understand when you add the libraries needed for SqlLite it wont affect the virtualenv python so you have to re-do all the steps and it will compile with the required libraries....